# Get an IP from the html code, BUT not the one inside href tag

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, ip, match

ONLY I'm trying go get the list of IP's from the string:

```
 <tr><td><a href="ip.php?ip=95.189.46.67">95.189.46.67</a></td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="ip.php?ip=92.126.26.179">92.126.26.179</a></td><td>1</td></tr>
```

I use 
var ips= ThisString.match(/\b\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b/g).join("\n");

Which gives me doubled list. I need ips that are between >< like >95.189.46.67<
.... Please...

Comment: Is there a class or ID on the table containing these elements?

Comment: Don't use a regular expression to parse HTML. Parse it into DOM elements, and then use DOM methods.

Comment: No, table doesn't have any identifier unfortunately...

Comment: Is your string is exactly as shown in the question, or is there more around it (i.e. the table element)? If not, I believe my answer should help out without requiring a table identifier

Answer (score 0):

If the table has an identifier (i.e. class `myTable`), you can [iterate over each of the anchor elements in the table row using jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), and use [jQuery.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to retrieve the contents:

```
$(".myTable tr td a").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8n9oynk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Put it into a table, then query out the created anchors' `textContent` properties

```
var myString = '<tr><td><a href="ip.php?ip=95.189.46.67">95.189.46.67</a></td><td>0</td></tr>\
<tr><td><a href="ip.php?ip=92.126.26.179">92.126.26.179</a></td><td>1</td></tr>';
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.innerHTML = myString;
var ips = [].slice.call(table.querySelectorAll('a[href*="?ip="]')).map(anchor => anchor.textContent);
```

Or if you really want to use regex and only get the text inside the anchor (presuming your string will always be just like this example), you could use this, but the above will be safer.

```
var ips = myString.match(/\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}(?=<)/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) so you can use the "><" characters explicitly, and also use capture groups to grab just the IPs:

```js
var rx = />(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})</g
var results;
while(results = rx.exec(document.body.innerHTML) !== null){
  console.log(results[1]);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td><a href="ip.php?ip=95.189.46.67">95.189.46.67</a></td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="ip.php?ip=92.126.26.179">92.126.26.179</a></td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Results printed to the console:

```
95.189.46.67
92.126.26.179
```